# Where can I find wisp essences and lazurite?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I'm trying to become a Knight Enchanter, and the training quest requires me to gather the materials for a spirit blade hilt.

But I've no idea where to actually find the required wisp essences and lazurite, and searching all areas manually could take a pretty long time.

Where can those ingredients be found?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Wisp Essence reportedly drops from *any* wraith in Fallow Mire, but I did not have any luck with that. Instead, like many others indicate, they seem to have a 100% drop rate from Pure Wraiths - slightly stronger enemies, which are found in a group of Wraiths, in one of three locations in Fallow Mire:

- Old Thoroughfare

[image]

- Granite Point

[image]

- Weeping Spires

[image]

As for the Lazurite, it can be found in the desert areas mostly. I had a lot of luck with the Forgotten Mine, which has 2 entrances just south and west of the first camp in The Western Approach.

Comment: Added map screenshots to your post, though they could probably be cleaned up and consolidated into one image.